A conditional inequality similar to the $abc$ conjecture?
Let $f_n(x):= \prod_{p|n} f_p(x)^{v_p(n)}$ for natural numbers $n$ and for primes $p$:
$$f_2(x):=x, f_p(x):=1+\prod_{q|p-1}f_q(x)^{v_q(p-1)} \text{ for } p > 2$$
Then: $n = \operatorname{rad}(n)\iff f_n(x)$ is a separable polynomial and using the Mason-Stothers theorem for natural numbers applied to $f_n(x)$ at $x=2$ we get the following:
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and the Wronskian $W(a,b):=a'b-b'a\neq 0 $ and $f_{a+b}(x) = f_a(x)+f_b(x)$ then we have:
$$ab(a+b) \le \operatorname{rad}(ab(a+b)) |a'b-b'a|$$
Let $d(n)$ denote the degree of the polynomial $f_n(x)$. One observes that the function $d(n)$ is completely additive and hence determined by prime values $d(p)= d(p-1)$. Furhtermore one can prove inductively first for primes $p$ , that :
$$d(p) \le \frac{\log(p)}{\log(2)}$$
and then using the additivity, one can prove that:
$$d(n) \le \frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}$$
This observation can be used to prove that at $x=2$ we have:
$$a' = f'_a(2) = \sum_{i=0}^{d(a)} i \cdot a_i 2^{i-1} \le d(a) \cdot a \le \frac{\log(a)}{\log(2)} \cdot a$$
I am writing this, because now, we can combine this observation with the Mason-Stothers inequality to obtain some abc-like inequality:
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and the Wronskian $W(a,b):=a'b-b'a\neq 0 $ and $f_{a+b}(x) = f_a(x)+f_b(x)$ then we have:
$$a+b \le \operatorname{rad}(ab(a+b)) \cdot \frac{\log(a)+\log(b)}{\log(2)}$$
The unconditional (independent of $f_n(x)$) inequality is wrong for the unbeaten abc-triplet:
$$(a,b,c) = (2,3^{10} 109, 23^5)$$
This does not contradict the conditional inequality since for this triplet we do not have $f_a(x)+f_b(x) = f_{a+b}(x)$.
Question: Is it possible to prove that there are an infinite number of triplets $(a,b,a+b)$ with $a+b$ being not prime, satisfying the conditions:
$$\gcd(a,b)=1,W(a,b)\neq 0, f_a(x)+f_b(x)=f_{a+b}(x)$$
